# HTTP Array Parameters with Struts 2 via an Ajax Call

Tags: jquery, ajax, struts2, type-conversion

I'm having an issue sending array parameters to a Struts 2 action class.  I am using struts 2.1.8.1.

Here is some example code:

```
public class MyAction extends ActionSupport {

    private String[] types;

    public String execute() {
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public String[] getTypes() {
        return types;
    }

    public void setTypes(String[] types) {
        this.types = types;
    }
}
```

The problem is when sending an array via the jquery ajax method:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'Myaction.action',
    data: {
        types: ["this", "is", "a", "test"]
    }
});
```

causes an exception to occur:

`ognl.ParseException: Encountered " "]" "] "" at line 1, column 7.`

How can I use jQuery to send the array to my Struts2 action class? Is there something along the lines of an interceptor that I need to include? Or is there an option in jQuery to remove this?

I also encountered this problem with the jQuery UI Sortable control, but I solved that using a regex to remove the "[]" characters.  I would like to avoid that, because that solution bothers me.  I suppose I could just build the string myself, instead of using the object notation, but unless you can convince me otherwise, I would like to use the object notation instead.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

IIRC Struts doesn't like the jQuery 1.4+ format, you can use the traditional format though, just put this any time before your [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) call:

```
$.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;
```

You can read more about the 1.4+ default vs traditional serialization in the [`$.param()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/), the best illustration is their short example:

```
// <=1.3.2: (traditional in 1.4+)
$.param({ a: [2,3,4] }) // "a=2&a=3&a=4"
// >=1.4: (default in 1.4+)
$.param({ a: [2,3,4] }) // "a[]=2&a[]=3&a[]=4"
```

Comment: Ok... How can I be up to date to this small but critical changes? Thank by your answer by the way