# How to parse parameters array with square brackets?

Tags: java, url, jakarta-ee, struts2

The user wants to add a tag and its related files. He will access the Struts2 action by following query URL:

```
Test/addTag?tag=java&files[]=1.java&files[]=2.java&files[]=3.java
```

In the past I was using `HttpServletRequest.getParameterValues()` method to parse the `files[]` parameter and it worked perfectly.

But after migrating the architecture to Struts2 (I was using JSP+Servlet before), it doesn't work anymore. I tried following ways to define the files[] field in Struts2 Acton, but neither works (it always return **null** when calling the getter method)

```
private String files;
private String[] files;
private List<String> files;
```

(By the way the `tag` parameter could be parsed correctly)

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19386253/1594449

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Struts2 doesn't like the `files[]=1.java&files[]=2.java` query string format.

Use the traditional `files=1.java&files=2.java` instead. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3508564/1594449).

Comment: Thanks! you even helped me solved the next question.. (I'm using jQuery to build the query URL)

Comment: Related: this is also the reason for the need to [alter the code of dropzone.js to make it work with Struts2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26080212/1654265), for example.