# Send array to Struts2 action with jQuery AJAX call

Tags: jquery, ajax, struts2

So far, I've been able to send a simple string to a Struts2 action class, via an AJAX call. This time I need to do the same, but with a String array, and so I've changed my code like this:

**1. AJAX call:**

```
var test = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "createexperiment4.action",
    data: { test : test },
    success:
        function()
        {
            window.location = "loadexperiments.action";
        }
});
```

**2. CreateExperiment4Action.java:**

```
private String[] test;

[...]

public void setTest(String[] test)
{
    this.test = test;
}
```

However, the data isn't arriving to the action calss. Also, I keep getting this warning, which of course must be the key to my problem:

> WARNING: Parameter [test[]] didn't match acceptedPattern pattern!

Maybe this is some kind of configuration issue?

Comment: Try setting `traditional: true,` in your ajax request

Comment: What exactly is being sent? Post output from dev network console.

Comment: Thanks @Musa, it made the trick. I already had tried `$.ajaxSettings.traditional = true; ` (saw it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508550/http-array-parameters-with-struts-2-via-an-ajax-call)), with no effect. If you post it as an answer I'll accept it, of course.

@AleksandrM, besides this test it will be an array containing the IDs of a set of (checked) checkboxes in a table.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

jQuery.ajax's default serialization for arrays appends a `[]` after the name (eg `test[]=1&test[]=2`), while frameworks like PHP recognizes this format, struts doesn't. In order to prevent this behaviour add the `traditional: true,` configuration to your ajax request, which will give something like `test=1&test=2`.

```
var test = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "createexperiment4.action",
    data: { test : test },
    traditional: true,
    success:
        function()
        {
            window.location = "loadexperiments.action";
        }
});
```